# Is there jsoup-like HTML parser for PHP?

Tags: php, html-parsing

I need HTML parser for PHP that can use CSS selectors to select elements, in Java we have jsuop. Is there such a library for PHP?

Comment: regex is not like jsoup, see examples here http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment

Comment: Oh just kidding - on SO everyone needs a proper regex to parse a piece of HTML code - it's just a tribute. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/); it uses CSS-style selection similar to jQuery, which by the sound of your description is similar to jsoup.

Answer (score 3):

I use this one: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/